# How to handle missing values in crossprod in R?

Tags: r, na, cross-product

I am trying to calculate the sum products of two vectors, but there is NA in one of them.

```
crossprod(c(4.5,4,4,3,NA), c(1,5,4,1,1))
```

In calculating, I want to treat NA as a zero. But in original data frame,I still want to keep it as NA for further data processing. Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cross product is more complex than a sum, you can define a new function which replaces NA in the arguments:

```
crossprod.replacena <- function(x, y, val=0) {
                                  crossprod(replace(x, is.na(x), val), 
                                            replace(y, is.na(y), val)
                                  )
                        }
```

Or you can call `replace` on your arguments without defining a function, as `replace` does not modify its arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would it be the same that first replace the NA by 0 and then make the operation?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `sum` function and tell it to ignore missing values:

```
sum(c(4.5,4,4,3,NA)*c(1,5,4,1,1), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it is just what I need.

Comment: @QYang I'm confused.  If this is exactly what you need, why did you not accept it?